# cordova-camera plugin - plugin making app go into portrait mode after taking a picture

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am writing an app with AngularJS 1.5, Ionic 1, and Cordova CLI 8.

I am using the cordova-camera plugin to take pictures. My app is portrait-only. Landscape is not supported.

After the user takes a picture, the entire app temporarily goes into landscape mode. It resolves itself but looks concerning. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
"cordova-android": "^8.0.0"
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3"

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic1 1.3.5
@ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.22

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
Cordova Plugins : no whitelisted plugins (15 plugins total)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\aubrey\Documents\AndroidSDK)
NodeJS : v8.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.4.1
OS : Windows 10

cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-28
Gradle: installed C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\Android\gradle\gradle-5.3.1\bin\gradle
```

[image]

Edit: I am passing these options into the camera plugin:

```
    var options = {
        targetWidth: 150,
        targetHeight: 150,
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: false,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: true
    };
```

Comment: what configs are you passing to your camera function?

Comment: OK I updated the question with those details.

Answer (score 0):

In your camera config, `correctOrientation: true` is set, which may be the problem as the doc says it will correct the device orientation. Please change it to `false`.

You should also lock your screen `orientation` in config.xml with the below code

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

If still the issue persists, you can install `cordova-plugin-screen-orientation` plugin and lock the orientation.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation`

The plugin adds the following to the screen object `(window.screen)`

```
// lock the device orientation
.orientation.lock('portrait')

// unlock the orientation
.orientation.unlock()

// current orientation
.orientation
```

Comment: I hope you have configured orientation in config.xml, can you explain how the app resolves itself means?

Comment: It just turns back to portrait by itself without any problems. How do I configure this in config.xml?     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />

Comment: oh, that's interesting. Is there any way that you could send across an apk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196522/discussion-between-user1261710-and-nidhin-joseph).